# Jackson in Spring MVC 3.1.2

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I'm having problems getting Jackson to work in my Spring app.

I'm using

- Spring MVC 3.1.2
- Jackson 1.9.1 mapper asl

I've added the Jackson library to /WEB-INF/lib/ folder and added  to my spring config file.

spring-config.xml

```
<!-- language: xml-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mason.server.controller"  />

<bean
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-CONTENT/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/messages/messages" />
</bean>
```

function in controller

```
<!-- language: java -->
@RequestMapping(value = "/get_json", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=*/*")
public @ResponseBody List<String> getTechList() {
    List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();

    countryList.add("test");

    return countryList;
}
```

When i go to localhost:8888/get_json i get a error 406.

I have tried a solutions on the internet but none of them seem to work. Any help would be appreciated!

PS: I use Spring MVC in combination with Google App Engine and Spring Security.

Comment: i got i working, i will post my solution soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got it working after 2 days. I forgot to add *jackson-core-asl-1.9.10* to my library and when i made a request using jQuery, everything worked. It does not working going to the link in a browser but i guess thats fine for now.

mvc-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mason.server.controller"  />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <property name="mediaTypes">
    <map>
      <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
      <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
    </map>
  </property>
  <property name="viewResolvers">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-CONTENT/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
      </bean>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
        <property name="prefixJson" value="true"/>
      </bean>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

test.jsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" " http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd ">
<html xmlns=" http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml ">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Request json test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    //attach a jQuery live event to the button
    $('#getdata-button').live('click', function(){
        $.getJSON('/get_json', function(data) {
            //alert(data); //uncomment this for debug
            //alert (data.item1+" "+data.item2+" "+data.item3); //further debug
            $('#showdata').html("<p>"+data+"</p>");
        });
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="getdata-button">Get JSON Data</a>
<div id="showdata"></div>
</body>
</html>
```